# Magento 2 How to change variable value using Plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have a execute method of controller which has array as item like

```
$data['array_key'] = $this->helper->someFunction();
```

now i want to change value of this item on some condition can any one please help me on how i can change this value using plugin.

Note: Please don't suggest preference.

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

Comment: No i used preference